# Get my Application Activity-Stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I got 3 activities in my app. Activity A,B and C.

I am in activity B now and I need to know if there are more activities in my activity stack or when I finish activity B I will exit the app.

I found [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) that can do the job, how ever it require `GET_TASKS` permision.

Is there any other way for doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is just no!

Answer (score 0):

While going from one activity to another activity you can set flags clear top to delete other activity those are now on stack and then go to new activity. If you do this then finish the current activity then you are out of the app.

For example

```
Intent imra = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MoreActivity.class);
                    imra.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(imra);
                    finish();
```